# It does not appear that the file is downloaded

Tags: scp

I have applied the following command:

scp xxLx@10.201.23:/Ejemplo/CLEAN.txt \Users\L\Downloads\CLEAN.txt

I am notified that the file is downloaded, but the file does not appear in the folder. My question is: Did the file actually download?

If it was downloaded, where or how can I access the file?

I am using Windows 10 and Cygwin64 Terminal to connect remotely.

**Note:** The username and address changed for security.

Comment: What's the output of your command? Did `scp` connect to the remote server? I think you should verify the local directory that it exists.

Comment: Yes, it is a remote connection, but my question is if the output address is not valid, the file is not downloaded or where do you download it? Because it told me that it had been downloaded, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was probably downloaded to a file named "UsersLDownloadsCLEAN.txt" in the *current* directory.

The backslash `\` is a special character within the Bash shell used inside Cygwin Terminal – because you left it unquoted, Bash interpreted every backslash as an escape character and translated `\U` ⇒ `U`, `\L` ⇒ `L`, etc. so the resulting command that was run was:

```
scp xxLx@10.201.23:/Ejemplo/CLEAN.txt UsersLDownloadsCLEAN.txt
```

If you want to use a backslash literally, then it must be either prefixed with another backslash (for example, `\\Users\\L`) or put in quotes (e.g either `"\Users\L"` or `'\Users\L'`).

But when using Cygwin commands, you should be specifying Cygwin-style paths, *not* Windows paths. For example, C:\Users\L is `/cygdrive/c/Users/L`.

(Alternatively, use the native Windows version of OpenSSH scp.exe that comes preinstalled with Windows 10 – you don't need Cygwin for that anymore – or the plink.exe that comes with PuTTY.)

Comment: in mingw (gitbash) it would be `/c/Users/L/Downloads/CLEAN.txt` .

Comment: Thank you very much, everything is clear to me and I also found the document with the name you suggested.